# Firebase function not running/logging

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase cloud function and for some reason it is not running or logging even with just `console.log("hello world")` inside. This is confusing me, I think the issue could be because of promises, but even so I think it should work with just a console.log().

I call the function like this:

```
const addJobFunction = firestore.functions().httpsCallable("addJob");
addJobFunction({companyName: comp[0].data.Name, jobTitle: this.state.jobTitle,
                    jobLink: this.state.jobLink, companyKey: this.state.company});
```

and the function looks like:

```
exports.addJob = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  console.log("hello world");
  db.collection("jobs")
    .add({
      company: data.companyName,
      title: data.jobTitle,
      link: data.jobLink,
      data: [],
    });
});
```

The result in my logs whether the database add is there or not (I.e just a console.log) is this.
[image: Firebase cloud function logs]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed `event.preventDefault()` in my form submit function.

Works like this:

```
submitJob = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.company);
    let comp = this.state.companies.filter((company) => {
      return company.key === this.state.company;
    });
    const addJobFunction = firestore.functions().httpsCallable("addJob");
    addJobFunction({
      companyName: comp[0].data.Name,
      jobTitle: this.state.jobTitle,
      jobLink: this.state.jobLink,
      companyKey: this.state.company,
    });
    this.setState({
        jobTitle: '',
        jobLink: '',
    })
  };
```